# Python "monitor on" by sendmessage doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, winapi

Here my code, which should turns monitor on and off. `turns_off` work, but when I call `turns_on`, when the monitor off, my diode from power button on monitor just lighting for few milliseconds, and nothing else (Of course it prints "Monitor turned on"). I still can turns monitor on by mouse movement.

```
import win32gui
import win32con


class Monitor:

    @staticmethod
    def turns_on():
        print("Monitor turned on")
        win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, -1)

    @staticmethod
    def turns_off():
        print("Monitor turned off")
        win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, 2)
```

**EDITED**

P.S. I've read, that `SendMessage` is blocking program, so I've replaced them to `PostMessage`, but problem is still actual.

```
class Monitor:

    @staticmethod
    def turns_on():
        print("Monitor turned on")
        win32gui.PostMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, -1)

    @staticmethod
    def turns_off():
        print("Monitor turned off")
        win32gui.PostMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, 2)
```

Comment: `SC_MONITORPOWER` is more likely an advice to monitor driver. In my case, the monitor shuts off instantly after `PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, -1);`

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT: That's the `turns_off` case that also works for OP.

Comment: The `turns_on` most likely fails because it doesn't affect the reason the screen went to sleep in the first place, and therefore it goes back to sleep again.  Try `SetThreadExecutionState`